# Having makefile related nightmare

Tags: makefile

If I try `make all`, I get:

```
make: ***No rule to make target 'src\SOURCES', needed by 'all'. Stop.
```

If I try `make qwark`, I get:

```
make: ***No rule to make target 'obj\src\SOURCES' needed by 'qwark'. Stop.
```

If I try `make qwark.o`, I get

```
Fatal error: can't create obj\qwark.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [qwark.o] Error 1
```

Here's my source code, for your viewing pleasure...

```
COMPILER := g++
CFLAGS := 
LDFLAGS := 
SOURCES := quark.cc
SOURCES := $(addprefix src\,SOURCES)
OBJECTS := $(addprefix obj\,$($(notdir SOURCES):.cc=.o))
EXECUTABLE := qwark.exe
DEBUG := bin\debug\$(EXECUTABLE)
NORMAL := bin\release\$(EXECUTABLE)

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

release: qwark
normal: qwark

qwark: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

qwark.o: src\qwark.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c src\qwark.cc -o obj\qwark.o

%.o: src\%.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(input) -o obj\$(output)
```

Please, someone, tell me what it is I'm doing wrong..........

Comment: Whence the backslashes?  Does `make` really recogniza those as directory separators?

Comment: @reinierpost Yes. Yes it does. I was compiling on a windows box, but for purposes of compatibility, this would be able to be made on a linux box also. I dunno about mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're modifying a literal `SOURCES` word, instead of the corresponding variable value. Try the following:

```
SOURCES := quark.cc

SOURCES := $(addprefix src\,$(SOURCES))
OBJECTS := $(addprefix obj\,$(patsubst %.cc,%.o,$(notdir $(SOURCES))))
```

Or, much simpler:

```
SOURCES := quark.cc

OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:%.cc=obj\%.o)
SOURCES := $(SOURCES:%=src\%)
```

Answer (score 2):

Expand the SOURCES variable when its on the rhs?

```
SOURCES := $(addprefix src\,$(SOURCES))
OBJECTS := $(addprefix obj\,$($(notdir $(SOURCES)):.cc=.o))
```

Comment: `$($(notdir $(SOURCES)):.cc=.o)` would expand a variable named `$(notdir $(SOURCES))` which is `quark.cc`.

Comment: Personally, I'd put the Makefile in src\ and not worry too much about the .o because I'd tell the vcs to ignore them.